# ServiceStack - how to add custom typescript decorators?

Tags: typescript, servicestack

I'm generating typescript dtos via C# models under ServiceStack.

I'm hoping to use [typestack/class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) which operates by evaluating several decorators that it provides.

Is there a way in ServiceStack's typescript generation for including arbitrary decorators beyond the usual DataAnnotations attributes on the C# side or must I create new C# attributes to mirror what I want to show up on the typescript side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

As [your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64583234/85785) is more UX-friendly I've also decided to implement this feature where you can instead use `[Emit{Language}]` attributes to generate code before each type or property, e.g:

```
[EmitTypeScript("@Validate()")]
public class User
{
    [EmitTypeScript("@IsNotEmpty()", "@IsEmail()")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

You can also use `[EmitCode]` to emit code for multiple languages, e.g. this adds annotations to both Dart & TypeScript.

```
[EmitCode(Lang.Dart | Lang.TypeScript, "@Validate()")]
public class User
{
    [EmitCode(Lang.Dart | Lang.TypeScript, new[]{ "@IsNotEmpty()", "@IsEmail()" })]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

---

In addition you can use the `PreTypeFilter`, `InnerTypeFilter` & `PostTypeFilter` to generate source code before and after a Type definition, e.g. this will append the `@validate()` annotation on non enum types:

```
TypeScriptGenerator.PreTypeFilter = (sb, type) => {
    if (!type.IsEnum.GetValueOrDefault())
    {
        sb.AppendLine("@Validate()");
    }
};
```

The `InnerTypeFilter` gets invoked just after the Type Definition which can be used to generate common members for all Types and interfaces, e.g:

```
TypeScriptGenerator.InnerTypeFilter = (sb, type) => {
    sb.AppendLine("id:string = `${Math.random()}`.substring(2);");
};
```

They previously didn't exist but I've also just added `PrePropertyFilter` & `PostPropertyFilter` for generating source before and after properties, e.g:

```
TypeScriptGenerator.PrePropertyFilter = (sb , prop, type) => {
    if (prop.Name == "Id")
    {
        sb.AppendLine("@IsInt()");
    }
};
```

Pre/Post PropertyFilter's are available from v5.9.3+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: this is lovely! i know we're not supposed to say thank you in comments...

while we're in this general space, allow me to ask for one more... could you provide one more filter that allows us to emit *inside* the class definition? i have some extra properties i'd like to add to every class on the typescript side that wouldn't come from the c#.

Comment: @Beej np, FYI the static `InnerTypeFilter` is now available on all languages, see updated answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

on top of @mythz enhancement, here's nicely terse shot at my end goal...

define c# attribute class to allow for adorning c# properties with decorators to be code generated into the corresponding typescript dtos:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class TypeScriptDecoratorsAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string[] Decorators { get; set; }
    public TypeScriptDecoratorsAttribute(params string[] decorators)
    {
        this.Decorators = decorators;
    }
}
```

then use the new `PrePropertyFilter` to emit:
(for example in Startup.cs)

```cs
TypeScriptGenerator.PrePropertyFilter = (sb, prop, type) => 
  prop.PropertyInfo.FirstAttribute<TypeScriptDecoratorsAttribute>()?.Decorators?.ForEach(d=> sb.AppendLine("// "+d));
```

fyi, Enumerable.ForEach() comes from [System.Interactive](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive/).

so this sample c# dto:

```cs
public class User
{
    [TypeScriptDecorators("@IsNotEmpty()", "@IsEmail()")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

will yield this typescript dto output:

```cs
export class User
{
    // @IsNotEmpty()
    // @IsEmail()
    public email?: string;

    public constructor(init?: Partial<User>) { (Object as any).assign(this, init); }
}
```

Comment: Great solution! That I've decided to add `[Emit*]` attributes for all languages where you can now use `[EmitTypeScript]` in the [latest v5.9.3+](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget#redownloading-myget-packages). See my updated answer for an example.